# Is this a correct implementation of an adapter pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, adapter

So I have two classes: SoccerPlayer and IceHockeyPlayer
They both have their own interface with some methods: ISoccerPlayer and IIceHockeyPlayer

SoccerPlayer:

```
public class SoccerPlayer implements ISoccerPlayer {

    public String[] teammembers;

    @Override
    public void kickFootball(int meters) {
        // Kick the football
    }

    @Override
    public void runForward(double speed) {
        // Run forward
    }

    @Override
    public void addTeammembers(String[] memberNames) {
        // Add the members
    }
}
```

IceHockeyPlayer:

```
public class IceHockeyPlayer implements IIceHockeyPlayer {

    public ArrayList<String> teammembers;

    @Override
    public void hitPuck(int meters) {
        // Hit the puck
    }

    @Override
    public void skateForward(double speed) {
        // Skate forward
    }

    @Override
    public void addTeammembers(ArrayList<String> memberNames) {
        // Add the members
    }

}
```

Next, I created a class which contains both a SoccerPlayer and an IceHockeyPlayer that implements both Interfaces, this would be my adapter.
The methods in this class just call the correct methods of either SoccerPlayer or IceHockeyPlayer:

```
public class Adapter implements ISoccerPlayer, IIceHockeyPlayer {

    public SoccerPlayer soccerplayer;
    public IceHockeyPlayer icehockeyplayer;

    public Adapter(SoccerPlayer soccerplayer, IceHockeyPlayer icehockeyplayer) {
        this.soccerplayer = soccerplayer;
        this.icehockeyplayer = icehockeyplayer;
    }

    // SoccerPlayer
    @Override
    public void kickFootball(int meters) {
        this.soccerplayer.kickFootball(meters);
    }

    @Override
    public void runForward(double speed) {
        this.soccerplayer.runForward(speed);
    }

    @Override
    public void addTeammembers(String[] memberNames) {
        this.soccerplayer.addTeammembers(memberNames);
    }

    // IceHockeyPlayer
    @Override
    public void hitPuck(int meters) {
        this.icehockeyplayer.hitPuck(meters);
    }

    @Override
    public void skateForward(double speed) {
        this.icehockeyplayer.skateForward(speed);
    }

    @Override
    public void addTeammembers(ArrayList<String> memberNames) {
        this.icehockeyplayer.addTeammembers(memberNames);
    }

}
```

Is this a correct implementation of an adapter pattern? If no, what would I need to change to make it one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's more of a Facade.

For an adapter, you'd have something like

```
interface SportsPlayer {
    public void play(int meters);
    public void move(double speed);
}
```

and adapters like

```
class IceHockeyPlayerAdapter implements SportsPlayer {
    private IceHockeyPlayer player;
    public IceHockeyPlayerAdapter(IceHockeyPlayer p) { player = p; }

    public void play(int meters) {
        player.playPuck(meters);
    }
    public void move(double speed) {
        player.skateForward(speed);
    }
}
```

which would "adapt" the hockey player to "become" a `SportsPlayer`; so it's actually a different method set.

EDIT:

Here's an adapter usage for the real JDK.

You know that you can use try-with-resources which will close resources automatically, and you can shutdown `ExecutorService`s after submitting your tasks? Well, try-with-resources demands an `AutoCloseable` and the `ExecutorService` doesn't implement that. An adapter to the rescue:

```
public class AutocloseableExecutorService implements ExecutorService, AutoCloseable {
    private ExecutorService delegate;
    public AutocloseableExecutorService(ExecutorService d) {
        delegate = d;
    }
    // delegate ExecutorService methods to implement the interface
    public void execute(Runnable r) { delegate.execute(r); 
    // ...

    // implement close() for AutoCloseable
    public void close() {
        delegate.shutdown();
    }
}
```

So now you can use it like this:

```
public void submitTasks(Runnable... rs) {
    try (AutocloseableExecutorService executor = new AutocloseableExecutorService(
             Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())) {
        for (Runnable r : rs) executor.submit();
    }
}
```

and the service will be registered for shutdown at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

It is not strictly speaking an adapter.
You use rather a composition of objects backed to 2 interfaces :

```
public class Adapter implements ISoccerPlayer, IIceHockeyPlayer
```

The GOF adapter pattern adapts generally one object (but it may be multiple) to **one specific interface** in order to allow to allows clients to manipulate the interface type while the adapted object(s) used in the adapter may not provide the methods required for the client interface.

For example take this client interface :

```
interface SportPlayer {
    void play();
}
```

Suppose that `SoccerPlayer` doesn't have `play()` method but a functionally equivalent method with another name : `playSoccer()`.
To be able to adapt a `SoccerPlayer` object to  `SportPlayer` you can create a `SoccerAdapter`  :

```
public class SoccerAdapter implements SportPlayer {
   private SoccerPlayer soccerPlayer;

   public SoccerAdapter(SoccerPlayer soccerPlayer){
      this.soccerPlayer = soccerPlayer;          
   }
   public void play(){
        soccerPlayer.playSoccer();
   }
}
```

Comment: It is not an adapter at all.

Comment: @lexicore Writing explanations takes time. Probably did the bad choice.

Answer (score 0):

No that's not the adapter pattern. You use an adapter to map behavior/methods of what a caller expects to what the provider provides.

Example:

Let's say you want to build a bot that handles your players. It just knows a player looks like this interface (I reuse your example, whether that's meaningful or not is out of scope for this question):

```
interface Player {
  void shoot(int meters);
  void move(double speed);
  addTeammembers(ArrayList<String> memberNames);
}
```

An adapter for that interface could look like this:

```
class SoccerPlayerAdapter implements Player {
  SoccerPlayer soccerplayer; //set via constructor

  void shoot(int meters) {
    soccerplayer.kickFootball(meters);
  }

  void move(double speed){
    soccerplayer.runForward(speed);
  }

  addTeammembers(ArrayList<String> memberNames) {
    soccerplayer.addTeammembers(memberNames);
  }
}
```

As you can see the `SoccerPlayerAdapter` "adapts" `SoccerPlayer` to `Player`, i.e. it maps the method `shoot(int meters)` to `kickFootball(int meters)` etc.

Note: you normally use adapters if the interfaces can't be directly implemented or it wouldn't make much sense to do so for other reasons. In your example (and thus mine) it would make more sense to just make the players directly implement the `Player` interface and refactor `kickFootball(meters)` to the more general method `shoot(meters)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Adapter pattern solves the problem when there is an existing `Consumer` code  and existing `Producer` code and there is an *incompatibility* between `Consumer` code accet type and `Producer` code produced type.

[`Consumer` and `Producer` code are not the standard terms, I prefer to use them for making my point easy to understand ]

To solve this issue we create a separate `Adapter` code which consumes the produced type from `Producer` code and *Transforms*  it to the type consumed by `Consumer` code.

```
 Consumer ---consume (TypeX) //accepts TypeX, Existing code
 Producer   ----produce () : TypeY //returns TypeY, Existing code
 Adapter     ---- adapt(TypeY) : TypeX //New code to work with two existing code.accepts TypeY adapts it to TypeX and returns the same.
```

For code you can refer (easy to understand) https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adapter-pattern/